# Assembling a jar using Maven containing only files in a specified folder

Tags: maven

I have the following Maven project structure.

```
project
    -- src
       -- main
          -- java
          -- models
       -- resources
```

I want to create and deploy a jar `project-models.jar` containing everything inside the folder `models` and nothing else. Since I'm not very familiar with Maven, I'd really appreciate if you could provide me some example.

Answer (score 0):

1. `models` belongs to `resources` (They should neither be compiled nor tested, should they?)
2. See [How to create an additional attached jar artifact from the project](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/attached-jar.html):

> Specify a list of fileset patterns to be included or excluded by adding `<includes>`/`<include>` or `<excludes>`/`<exclude>` and add a `classifier` in your `pom.xml`.
>
> Note: the jar-plugin must be defined in a new execution, otherwise it will replace the default use of the jar-plugin instead of adding a second artifact. The `classifier` is also required to create more than one artifact.